# Simple Order By DESC not working

Tags: php, mysql

This is my first go at MySQL and I can't seem to grasp why this simple query is not working,

- I am trying to sort my users by their `avg_total` *(average
  total=highest_score/num_tries).*
- I don't want to display users who do not have a highest score
  yet(default SQL value for highest score is none, and my app overrides
  that on succesful completion of the last stage of the app)

Therefore I would reckon that my query would go like this:

```
$query = "SELECT pic_square,name,highest_score,num_tries,avg_total FROM users WHERE NOT highest_score = 'none' ORDER BY avg_total DESC";
```

> Unfortunately my results are not ordered by DESCENDING order based on
>   their average total, for some reason:

**As I see it it should be like this:**

1. Phanos
2. Martha
3. Nicholas

**instead of:**

1. Martha
2. Nicholas
3. Phanos

[image: MySQL order by query example image and results]

Comment: What datatype is your `avg_total` column?

Comment: Well, it's VARCHAR - it should be INT right?

Comment: float is better, your image suggests.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides float or decimal should work fine

Comment: It should be FLOAT as my image suggests

Comment: `should be` !== `is`: the name would suggest it should be a numeric type, but the order you're getting suggests varchar

Comment: @MarkBaker shoot it as an answer and i'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is your data type to column `avg_total`.It will work fine if u change ur datatype from `varchar` to `float`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `INT` column type for points, not `CHAR`, `VARCHAR` an other string types.

For empty values use `0` or `NULL` (depends on situation), not `'NONE'`.

Answer (score 1):

Try casting avg_total to float:

```
$query = "SELECT pic_square,name,highest_score,num_tries,(convert(avg_total, float))FROM users WHERE highest_score <> 'none' ORDER BY avg_total DESC";
```

Comment: Nice I like this a lot but it feels like a hack

Comment: Yes, I know. My intention was that you didn't have to change anything else than the query.